# React Js Login Beginner

Tags: reactjs

first of all I am a very beginner at React.js. I am creating my super simple static code which has to login the user by the credentials provided in the state and redirect to homepage. But for some reason it doesn't work and doesn't redirect me to the homepage, which has the route of *****'/'*****, btw my Login route is *'/login'*. I would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class LoginPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loginData: {
                username: 'test',
                password: 'test'
            },
            errors: {}
        };
        this.buttonClickHandle = this.buttonClickHandle.bind(this);
        this.loginHandle = this.loginHandle.bind(this);
    }

    loginHandle(event) {
        let field = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;

        let loginData = this.state.loginData;
        loginData[field] = value;

        this.setState({loginData: loginData});
    }

    buttonClickHandle(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if ( this.state.loginData.username === this.target.username) {
            console.log("User exists. Go to the login page");
            return <Redirect to="/"/>
        } else {
            console.log("User doesn't exists. Show error message");
        }
    }

    render() {
    
    return (
        <div className="loginPage">
            <Container maxWidth="sm">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onChange={this.loginHandle}>
                    <div className="loginForm">
                        <TextField
                            required
                            id="outlined-required"
                            label="E-mail"
                            variant="outlined"
                            placeholder="Your e-mail..."
                            className="loginInput"
                        />
                        <TextField
                            required
                            id="outlined-password-input"
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            autoComplete="current-password"
                            variant="outlined"
                            placeholder="Your password..."
                            className="loginInput"
                        />
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={this.buttonClickHandle}
                        >
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default LoginPage
```

Comment: you need to check against `event.target.username.value`, not `this.target.username`

Comment: As ludwiguer said, it appears that `this.target` isn't defined so the logic for redirection never runs

Comment: Also, to access the form elements you need to set a name `<TextField name="username"...`

Comment: @ludwiguer @itsanewabstract thank you, I have changed `this.target.username` and `this.target.password` to `event.target.username.value` and `event.target.password.value`. Also in `TextField` I have added `name="username"` and `value={this.state.loginData.username}`. As well as `onClick={this.buttonClickHandle.bind(this)}` in Button. But now it shows me that the value is undefined, still not working.

Comment: except this, i just realized that my `onChange={this.loginHandle}` in form is never called.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that look off in your code.

- There is no `onChange` prop in forms only `onSubmit`
- The button should trigger the onSubmit function, this is done by setting the type of the button as `submit`
- To get the input values from the form you need to put a name and get them as `event.target.name.value` inside the onSubmit function

here is a working example of your code

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loginData: {
        username: "test",
        password: "test"
      },
      errors: {}
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      this.state.loginData.username === event.target.username.value &&
      this.state.loginData.password === event.target.password.value
    ) {
      console.log("User exists. Go to the login page");
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    } else {
      console.log("User doesn't exists. Show error message");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="loginPage">
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="loginForm">
              <TextField
                required
                name="username"
                id="outlined-required"
                label="E-mail"
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder="Your e-mail..."
                className="loginInput"
              />
              <TextField
                required
                name="password"
                id="outlined-password-input"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder="Your password..."
                className="loginInput"
              />
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
                Login
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginPage;
```